# use database in android app to save gps location

Tags: java, android, database, gps

I'm new to programming, and I'm trying to make a android application. I want to make a button, that when you press it it will save your GPS location in an database. I can make a simple access database, but I'm not even sure if access can be used. Could someone, please help me with the java coding to link java to the database.

Thank you !

Comment: Simple googling will provide you with lot of online resources

Answer (score 0):

```
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("mydb.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gps_details (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Latitude REAL, Longitude REAL);");

     ContentValues values;
     values = new ContentValues();
     values.put("Latitude", latitudeValue);
     values.put("Longitude", longitudeValue);

     db.insert("gps_details", null, values);
     db.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Some hints, start here for some information on how to get the location

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html

And go on here with information on how to work with databases in Android

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Sections 1. - 4. of this

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

tutorial will provide some more valuable information on handling databases

I'd advise not to copy&paste some code you find here or on the web, but rather read the necessary documents to actually learn how it works